# C# private class MyColors

Tags: c#

```
private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
   public MyRenderer() :base(new MyColors()){ }
}

private class MyColors 
{
   public override Color MenuItemSelected
   {
      get { return Color.; }
   }
}
```

I am struggling getting my errors to be fixed. I have an error on the

```
base(new MyColors())
```

line and then again on the

```
public override Color MenuItemSelected
```

line and lastly on

```
get { return Color. ;}
```

The errors are
CS1503
CS0115
CS1001
respectively. I am not sure how to fix these but I think if I fix the first one I can make out the others.

Comment: And what are those errors, i have memorized 4000 other error codes, just not those. Maybe its the period after color  `Color.` but who knows `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: `class MyColors  : ProfessionalColorTable`. And the final error is an unfinished line, unclear what `Color` you wanted

Answer (score 2):

First you need to change you methods to public instead of private.
Then you need to use `()` to declare the function.
Also, you need to declare the variable you will return of type `Color` (I will call it `m_color`
Then you need to remove the `get` and leave only the `return` (and remove the extra `.` you have)

You should have something like this:

```
public class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
   public MyRenderer() :base(new MyColors()){ }
}

public class MyColors 
{
   private Color m_color;

   public override Color MenuItemSelected()
   {
      return m_color;
   }
}
```

Comment: The **m_** stands for Member Variable, you can use your own coding naming convention.